# When I use to selenium java test script retrieve data from angular model but run time I get : no such element: Unable to locate element: errors

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, angularjs, selenium

I get the following error when I use to selenium Java test script to retrieve data from angular model *no such element: Unable to locate element: errors*

```
<div class="col-md-11 textfielddiv">
<textarea id="textboxc7f95f05-5de7-497f-b91f-20df0fc69120" class="form-control textfield ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" ng-model="chatPane.textmessage" ng-keypress="isType(chatPane.VisitorId)" ng-enter="sendChat(chatPane.VisitorId)" placeholder="Type your message here" cols="50" rows="3" aria-invalid="false"/>
</div>
```

**To retrieve data, I use below code**:

```
 Login1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[ng-model='chatPane.VisitorId']"));
System.out.println("chatPane.textmessage+ "+Login1.getAttribute("value"));
```

**Run time error**

```
 org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input[ng-model='chatPane.VisitorId']"}
  (Session info: chrome=51.0.2704.103)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see `input` tag there. Try this:

```
 Login1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("textarea[ng-model='chatPane.textmessage']"));
 // I don't see value attribute either.
 System.out.println( chatPane.textmessage +Login1.getAttribute("value"));
```

you can get inner HTML text with `Login1.getAttribute("innerHTML");`  However, I do not see any text here.

Comment: The original poster's cssSelector also had the value of the ng-model attribute wrong too.  This answer should do it.

Comment: I corrected the mistake Thankz.
Actually I want to retrieve VisitorId, from chatPane.VisitorId

Comment: I use java code – 
WebElement Login = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("textarea[ng-model='isType(chatPane.VisitorId)']"));

Or 
WebElement Login = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("textarea[ng-model='chatPane.VisitorId']"));  but it didn't work. do you have any idea about this.

Comment: Since you want to get VisitorID get Attribute "ng-enter".

Login1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("textarea[ng-model='chatPane.textmessage']"));
String visitorId=Login1.getAttribute("ng-enter");
I hope it gives the text if it doesn't return text. Then try this.

String visitorId=((JavascriptExecuter)driver.executeScript(chatPane.VisitorId);
I hope it works. Let me know in comment.

Comment: JavascriptExecutor*